# Volunteerism vs volunteering

Tags: differences

What would be the difference between saying "I engage in volunteerism" and saying "I engage in volunteering" ?

Volunteerism is defined as "the use or involvement of volunteer labor, especially in community services" not to be confused with voluntarism which is a philosophy that involves not using coercion.

This definition is taken from [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/volunteerism?q=Volunteerism).

Comment: I would read the first as "I use volunteers" and the second as "I am a volunteer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try writing it out long form (both definitons from ODO: [volunteerism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/volunteerism?q=Volunteerism), [volunteering](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/volunteer?q=volunteering#volunteer__11))

> I engage in the use or involvement of volunteer labour, especially in community services.

vs

> I engage in working for an organization without being paid.

They are clearly different. *Volunteerism* is describing a way an organisation gets things done. *Volunteering* (in this context) describes how an individual interacts with an organisation.